# What could be the causes that Hyper-V would pause running virtual machines by it self?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, pausing-execution

What could be the causes that Hyper-V would pause running virtual machines by it self?

We have encountered that problem twice recently. Our 2 VMs have 4 Gb of ram each and does not have a lot of traffic. I think we have something like 50gb of space left reserved to VM backup. Could it be due to missing space to backup the snapshots of the VM?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

check Your logs why it paused.  Event Viewer is Your friend :)
here is how to check logs for that: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2486243
I saw with Hyper-V VMs paused when I ran out of space so You may be correct.